# Problems with Infrared circuit on a PCB - Is it the board or schematic?

Tags: pcb, sensor, raspberry-pi, schematics, infrared

I am using the toner transfer method to apply my circuit for 6 sets of infrared emitters and collectors connected to an RJ15 cable on a PCB for use with a Raspberry Pi B+ board (connected via IDE cable).  The circuit for a single emitter and collector works (82 ohm resistor to ground on emitter, and GPIO on power in front of a 10k resistor for the collector).  I created the schematic and board in Eagle and then created the physical PCB.  To my confusion, it did not work with a single RJ15 plugged in to one of the 6 jacks.  I didn't wire them in series.  I used an LED between traces on the board to find that there is power, but no signal from the IR collector.  Is it possible that I've somehow made a mistake in my schematic or final .brd file?  If not, I guess the problem is with the physical board.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also describe the IR part of the circuit and how they connect to the jacks? And for troubleshooting, get out the multimeter and check continuity from end (SV1) to end (IR emitter) - some wires may be crossed.

Comment: Since you apear to be etching the board yourself - what method have you used to connect your top & bottom layers on the board?